# C# how to deal with integer overflows when returning status code from application in unix environment

Tags: c#, windows, unix, exit-code

I have a program similar to this

```
public static class Program
{
    public const int BAD_SCRIPT = 1337;

    private static async Task<int> main(string[] args)
    {
        string script = ParseArguments(args);
        return await GetSomeResult(script);
    }
    
    private static async Task<int> GetSomeResult(string script)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(script) ? BAD_SCRIPT : 0;
    }
}
```

This works fine on the windows environment and returns the expected error. However, in Unix it returns the modulus of 256 due to integer overflow. My question to you is how do I deal with this scenario? This causes the API request to return a wrong error.

Comment: have you tried to change the return type to long, int32 or uint? I don't thing that would affect anything on windows.

Comment: Wouldn't that still cause overflow in UX environment?

Comment: Where is this result coming from? Is it a function, or is it the exit code of an application?

Comment: Never mind, I should have just set the constant variable to be a byte. That way it will work for both environments.

Comment: It's an exit code of the application @Charlieface . Which simply returns the defined constant in the class.

Comment: So POSIX systems only support exit codes up to 255. I suggest you find a better way to communicate error conditions, a single byte isn't going to hold much info. Perhaps use `stderr`

Comment: Could you show me an example of stderr usage? @Charlieface

Comment: Well I haven't the faintest idea how you are actually executing this application, but using the `Process` class there is the `StandardError` property which is a stream